# How to drop rows with condition to match string value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe where one of the columns has values as either "TRUE" or "FALSE". I want to get rid of the rows having column value = "TRUE". The name of that column is "is_duplicate" and dataframe name is "z".

I have tried the following approach:

```py
i=0
while(i<len(z)):
    check=z["is_duplicate"].iloc[i:i+1]
    check=check.to_string(index=False)
    if(check=="TRUE"):
        z=z.drop([i],axis=0)
    i=i+1
```

I also tried 2 more approaches based on the threads given on the similar topic but none of them work for me.

```py
z = z.replace('TRUE', np.nan).dropna()
```

```py
z=z[z["is_duplicate"] == "FALSE"]
```

I'm new to coding and have not been able to get this done even though it looks like the most basic thing ever.

Comment: This should work `z=z[z["is_duplicate"] == "FALSE"]`. Did you get any errors?

Comment: No, no errors. But it also removes a few values that were in fact "FALSE".

Comment: That's peculiar. what does `z["is_duplicate"].unique()` return?

Comment: it returns [True False 'False']

Comment: i just changed all the capital letters into small thinking maybe that was the problem, but still I don't understand how there are 3 unique values to this.

Comment: You have mixed datatypes. You have boolean and string both in the column

Comment: Try the answer I provided and let me know if it works :)

Comment: I got it!!! I had modified a few cells based on some conditions and set them as "False". I changed that to boolean False without the quotes. It works just fine now. Thank you so much for your help!! to think I had been scratching my head for hours over something so trivial!

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
z= z[~z['is_duplicate']=='TRUE']
```

or

```
z=z[~z['is_duplicate']=='FALSE']
```

if your `z['is_duplicate'].unique()` returns `[True False 'FALSE']`, then first replace 'False' with False(Boolean):

```
z['is_duplicate'] = z['is_duplicate'].map({'False': False})
```

Then try:

```
z = z[~z['is_duplicate']]
```

Comment: try with `z[z.eval(z.is_duplicate)]`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for,

```
z.drop(z[z['is_duplicate']==True].index, axis=0)
```

Thanks